# C++ concrete type with multiple implementations

Tags: c++

I am designing a distributed algorithm and I've separated the functionality as follows:

```
class Peer {
public:
  void send(PeerId destination, ...) //send some data
}

class MyDistributedAlgorithm {
public:
  MyDistributedAlgorithm(Peer& self);
  doX(); //calls self.send()
}
```

The value of separating it out this way is that I can reuse the algorithm for different implementations of Peer (tcp/ip sockets, or threads, etc.)

One thing I realize is that PeerId may depend on the implementation of Peer, yet MyDistributedAlgorithm needs to store a map with keys of type PeerId so it must be a concrete type.

I'm fairly inexperienced in C++, in C, my solution for this problem would be to define PeerId as a void* and just cast it as necessary for each Peer implementation. Is there a better way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `PeerId` a classical inheritance hierarchy; since
none of the actual derived classes would probably have a pointer
(since they are really values), using `std::shared_ptr` (or
`boost::shared_ptr`, if you don't have C++11) would probably be
safe.

Alternatively, you could have `PeerId` wrap the (shared)
pointer; provide it with necessary interface, and have it
forward to the pointed to implementation.

I'm supposing here that `PeerId` is immutable (except for
assignment).  That seems the most likely case for an identifier,
but if not, you'll have to consider the fact that the
suggestions above implement reference semantics, rather than the
expected value semantics.  (With immutable objects, you can't
really tell the difference between the two.)

Comment: Could you dumb down your explanation a bit? I'm not sure what you mean by classical inheritance hierarchy (what are the base classes and what are the derived classes?) or what that has to do with a pointer. PeerId is immutable.

Comment: I can't really explain inheritance or polymorphism in the small space available here.  I'd suggest you get a good teaching text, say _Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++_ (by Stroustrup) and study it.  Inheritance is one of the fundamental tools in C++.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I understand inheritance. I'm not sure how you're proposing I use it here.

Comment: @dschatz If you're familiar with design patterns, it's the strategy pattern.  Make `PeerId` polymorphic: define an abstract base class which defines the interface you need, and provide the necessary implementations.  Polymorphism requires reference semantics (passing pointers rather than the objects); you can either expose them, or wrap them in a class.  And then define the comparison necessary for the map, and instantiate the map over it.

Comment: Wouldn't I be better off using the pimpl idiom for this then? It allows me to decide the implementation of PeerId at link time.

Comment: If in any one executable, there will be only one type of `PeerId`, then resolving the type are link time (e.g. the compilation firewall idiom) is a very good idea.  I was under the idea that you would have several different types in the same executable; in that case, you would need runtime resolution (provided by virtual functions).  (The compilation firewall idiom is more or less my wrapper class.)